# Building master Parse-Dashboard from AWS EB

Tags: parse-server, parse-dashboard

I currently have no problems installing parse-dashboard 2.1.0 on my AWS EB instance.

However, when I try to point it to the master version ("parse-dashboard": "github:parse-community/parse-dashboard#master"), my instance doesn't deploy, due to puppeteer issues (I think it's required by react somewhere).

This is similar to the issue with Parse-Server master and EB, where /lib is .gitignore, so you can't point it to the master git.

Is there any work around for this without having to install puppeteer?

Thanks!

Comment: You can create a for of the Parse Dashboard project and remove lib from gitignore in your fork.

Comment: Thanks @DaviMacêdo, you must be getting sick of me demanding all your attention .

The .gitignore does not contain a /lib directory for Parse Dashboard. Here is the contents:

.DS_Store
node_modules/
bundles/
PIG/bundles/
Parse-Dashboard/public/bundles/
Parse-Dashboard/parse-dashboard-config.json
npm-debug.log
.eslintcache

// vim .swp
*.swp
.env
.idea/

logs/
test_logs

Comment: No problem :) I am happy to see your contributions. Try to remove from your .gitignore: bundles/
PIG/bundles/
Parse-Dashboard/public/bundles/

Comment: Still errors installing Puppeteer :/

Comment: I am not expert in EB but I recently had problems installing puppeteer and I had to use --unsafe-perm flag on my npm install command. Maybe there is someway to specify this flag to be used in EB?